# Regex for all strings over L={0,1} ending with an even number of 0s

Tags: regex

sorry for the novice question by I've looked and can't seem to find a question that addressed this.
I want a regex that describes all strings over L={0,1} ending with an even number of 0s.
Examples: 00, 0000, 100, 0100, 001100... basically anything starting with 0 or 1 and ending with an even number of 0s

This is what I've got so far: ((0|1)*1)00+ but this doesn't allow me to get 00 since that must be a 1 always. I can't find a way to put as many 0s as I want at the beginning without having to put that 1.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since zero is an even number, empty strings and all strings of zeroes in ones that end in one satisfy your requirement. Please edit to clarify whether the minimum number of zeroes at the end of the string is zero or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
^([01]*1)?(00)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture group

  - `[01]*1` Match zero or more repetitions of either 0 or 1 followed by matching 1
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional using `?`
- `(00)+` Match one or more repetitions of `00`
- `$` End of string

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ks4Gob/1).

If supported, you can also use non capture groups `(?:`

Comment: It's a CS assignment I'm not sure what "?" means

Comment: @MoudhafferBouallegui the `?` makes the group `([01]*1)` optional so you can also match 00. I have updated the answer with a bit more detail.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last line? I had assumed (incorrectly, it appears) that non-capture groups would be supported by all regex engines.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sed for example does not support non capture groups. You could check for example this page https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html and then in the dropdowns at the top specify the flavour to see the supported features. POSIX BRE for example does not support it.

Answer (score 2):

An even number of 0s is `(00)*`. It needs to be at the end, so that part of the regex will be `(00)*$`.

What precedes that even number of 0s? Either *nothing* or an arbitrary sequence of 0s and 1s ending with a 1. So that's `(|[01]*1)`.

Putting it together, we have:

```
^(|[01]*1)(00)*$
```

(I'm assuming extended regex syntax, where `(`, `)`, and `|` don't have to be escaped. Adjust the syntax as needed.)

I have not tested this.

Comment: Wouldn't this allow someone to get 01 for example, or better yet an empty string?

Comment: @MoudhafferBouallegui Yes. Both "01" and "" end with an even number of 0s. If the even number has to be at least 2, that's a different problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, good catch. I've updated my answer, changing the regexp from `^(|[01]*)(00)*$` to `^(|[01]*1)(00)*$`